# How to get part of text, string containing a phrase/word?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in MySQL that i process with PHP. In this database i have a column with long text. People search for some phrases with the search tool on the website. It displays items matching this search.

Now, my question is how to get a part of the text that contains the phrase they search for so that they can see if it's what they looking for?

For example:

```
Text: "this is some long text (...) about problems with jQuery and other JavaScript frameworks (...) so check it out"
```

And now i would like to get for phrase jQuery this:

```
about problems with jQuery and other JavaScript frameworks
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use a combination of [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) (or [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)), and [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, LOCATE('jQuery', col) - 20, 40) AS snippet
FROM yourtable
```

This will select a 40 character snippet from your text, starting 20 characters before the first occurrence of `'jQuery'`.

However, it tends to be slow. Alternatives worth looking into:

- Using a similar method in PHP
- Using full-text search features from MySQL (not sure if any of them will help), or maybe a whole separate full-text search engine like solr.

Comment: Hm, if `LOCATE('jQuery', col) - 20` is negative, `SUBSTRING` will operate backwards (from the end of the string)... I'll try to figure out a workaround. What about the php equivalent with `strpos` and `substr`.

Comment: welll.. i could use it but hoped for some ready solution.I know it's lazy, but you know... why to open open door

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: can u be more specific? this i know

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the first occurrence of the phrase you a looking for. Then do a subtraction backwards to get a number less than yo first occurrence. Then call [mb_strimwidth()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php). Here is an example code

we will search for the word '*website*'.

```
//Your string
$string = "Stackoverflow is the best *website* there ever is and ever will be. I find so much information here. And its fun and interactive too";

// first occurence of the word '*website*' - how far backwards you want to print
$position=intval(strpos($string, '*website*'))-50;
$display_text=mb_strimwidth($string, $position, 300, '...<a href="link_here">more</a>'); 
//we will print 300 characters only for display.

echo $display_text;
```

Like a boss.